# how can we use the Animation and move on a sprite simultaneously in cocos2d-android?

Tags: cocos2d-android

Animation and move the sprite of one position to another position is done but simultaneously not working.
Anyone have an idea, how can I resolve it ??

Comment: run a move, then run an animate action. Should work. What have you tried?

Comment: i tried like this :  sprite.runAction(CCSequence.actions(action, actionMove,action_back ));

Comment: now its work fine through this : 
sprite.runAction(action);
sprite.runAction(actionMove);
sprite.runAction(action_back);

Comment: have you any idea cz both things are same but one is working fine and another not ??

Comment: sequence != simultaneous. The sequence runs actions one after the other. Calling runAction multiple times runs the actions in parallel (simultaneously).

Comment: thanks for the explaining this thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments to your question, you can simply call runAction once for every action you want to run and they will run in parallel, like so

```
sprite.runAction( action );
sprite.runAction( actionMove );
sprite.runAction( action_back );
```

If you would want to combine your actions into one parallel action, use CCSpawn

```
CCFiniteTimeAction parallelAction = CCSpawn.actions( action, actionMove, action_back );
sprite.runAction( parallelAction );
```

Now, running parallelAction will run action, actionMove and action_back in parallel.